# Does code inside `isDev()` if blocks gets deleted after a prod build ? (Tree shaking)

Tags: angular

I want to put some big debugging code inside a `isDev()` if block like:

```
if(isDev()) {
 // create a log of debug stuff here
}
```

My question is, is that code shipped to the build production? and If yes. Is there a good way to add code that does not ship to production without manually remove it?

Comment: Yes, It won't be removed.

Comment: Do you know another way to inject just dev time code @HsuanLee ?

Comment: Write the code to another file and replace it in `angular.json `(configurations > production > fileReplacements), just like `environment.prod.ts`.

Comment: I did it but looks like it stills carries the file.